# How can I get MacVim to properly indent my .vimrc

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm going through the [VimCasts.org archive](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/archive/) of videos and [number 5](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/indentation-commands/) covers using Vim's auto-indentation to format source code. I see it working properly in my Objective-C file but not my `.vimrc`.

My tab settings are as follows:

```
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab
```

My `.vimrc` file has the following `if` block:

```
if has("autocmd")
filetype on
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.rss,*.atom setfiletype xml
autocmd BufWritePre *.py,*.js :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
endif
```

I would think that if I placed the cursor on the first line above and pressed `Vjjjj=` I would get the second, third and fourth line indented by two spaces, but what I get instead is:

```
if has("autocmd")
filetype on
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.rss,*.atom setfiletype xml
autocmd BufWritePre *.py,*.js :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
    endif
```

Are my expectations incorrect or is this correct for some reason given the Vimscript language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `filetype plugin indent on` to your vimrc to get vim to do indentation properly. (The plugin part isn't really necessary but is nice to have)

I would recommend replacing the `filetype on` line with `filetype plugin indent on`

Comment: I did that and sourced the `.vimrc` file but there was no change in the behavior. I also searched through the `.vimrc` file for `filetype` and the only occurrences were within the code block that I quoted. But I'll `:h` the `filetype` command and see if what I read there helps.

Comment: @Chuck post your whole vimrc

Comment: Well, it'll be embarrassing. :) I'm working through multiple tutorials on Vim and Vimscript, so most of what's in there is code that I'm experimenting with, but here it is: http://pastebin.com/5nP7VyQ4

Comment: @Chuck did you reopen vim after changing the line or did you resource your vimrc? Because changing that line works for me. The only other thing you could check is does your vim support autocmd. (`echo has("autocmd")` should return 1). BTW it works for me using your vimrc.

Comment: I had sourced it, but closing all the windows and opening the `.vimrc` again worked. ty.